Strange single underline in visual studio
I'm working with C# in Visual Studio and I'm encountering an issue that I can't seem to resolve. There's a small single underline beneath one of the characters in my code, and no matter what I do, I can't get rid of it. When I try to delete the character associated with the underline, instead of disappearing, the underline jumps forward to the previous character. It seems to follow the deletion rather than being removed. I've tried various ways to remove it but haven't had any success. Could you help me figure out what's causing this and how I can fix it?


Try disabling CodeLens temporarily to see if the underline disappears.
Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens and uncheck the "Enable CodeLens" box.
Rarely, issues with custom fonts or rendering in the Visual Studio editor can lead to strange underlines or misplaced visual indicators.
Try changing the font or resetting the editor settings to default: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Set the font back to Consolas or another default option and check if the underline disappears.
